# carrierwave + nested models: file_field not calling "create" method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, nested-forms

I am trying to follow Railscast Ep 381 to integrate multi-file upload into my Rails app.  For my app, the Projects model has many Steps, and Steps have many Images.  The Image model is using a Carrierwave uploader.

Right now, I'm able to upload single image files from within the edit_steps path.  But I'm trying to design the upload interface so that a gallery on the edit_steps page automatically refreshes once new images have been added (so once images have been selected but the form has not yet been submitted).

According to the Railscast episode, when you select images, they should automatically call the create action for each file.  But my application is clearly not doing that.  How can I ensure that the create method of the Image model is being called?

step.rb

```
class Step < ActiveRecord::Base
    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :number

    attr_accessible :description, :name, :number, :project_id, :images_attributes
    belongs_to :project
    has_many :images
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :allow_destroy => :true

end
```

image.rb

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :project_id, :step_id, :file, :caption

  belongs_to :step
  belongs_to :project

  mount_uploader :file, FileUploader
end
```

views/steps/edit.html.erb

```
%= semantic_form_for [@project, @step], :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
<%= f.inputs do%>

....

    <div id="images">
        <%= render :partial => 'images/image', :collection => @step.images.all %>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

....

        <%= f.fields_for :images, Image.new do |image_form| %>
          <%= image_form.file_field :file, multiple: true, name: "image[file]"%>
        <%end%>
```

javascript/images.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  $('#new_image').fileupload
    dataType: "script"
```

controllers/images.controller

```
 def create
    @image = Image.create(params[:image])
  end
```

images/create.js.erb

```
<% if @image.new_record? %>
  alert("Failed to upload image: <%= j @image.errors.full_messages.join(', ').html_safe %>");
<% else %>
  alert("adding images")
  $("#images").append("<%= j render(@image) %>");
<% end %>
```